# Access class function in Web Component from inline Element

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I want to execute a defined class function from an Element inside my Web Component:

```
customElements.define('first-component', class FirstComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
     }

     log() {
        console.log('Well Done!')
     }

     connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = '<button onclick="log()">Do it</button>'
     }
});
```

State right now: **ReferenceError: log is not defined**

Answer (score 10):

**With parentElement, or closest()**

In order to call the `log()` method of the custom element, you'll have to get a reference on it.

In your example, the custom element is the parent element of the `<button>` element, so you should call the `parentElement` property of the button as already stated by @Smankusors:

```
<button onclick="this.parentElement.log()>Do it</button>
```

---

**With getRootNode()**

Alternately, in a more complex DOM tree, and if a Shadow DOM is used, you can use `getRootNode()` combined with `host` to get the custom element reference.

```js
customElements.define('first-component', class FirstComponent extends HTMLElement {
     log() {
        console.log('Well Done!')
     }

     connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
            .innerHTML = '<button onclick="this.getRootNode().host.log()">Do it</button>'
     }
})
```

```html
<first-component></first-component>
```

---

**With a unique identifier**

You can also call the custom element by its `id` property (if it has one) :

```js
customElements.define('first-component', class FirstComponent extends HTMLElement {
     log() {
        console.log('Well Done!')
     }

     connectedCallback() {
        if (!this.id)
            this.id = "_id"
        this.innerHTML = `<button onclick="${this.id}.log()">Do it</button>`
     }
})
```

```html
<first-component></first-component>
```

---

**With handleEvent()**

For security reasons, you can avoid inline script and implement the `handleEvent()` method, then call inside it a specific method depending on some  criterions :

```js
customElements.define('first-component', class FirstComponent extends HTMLElement {
    log() {
        console.log('Well Done!')
    }
     
    handleEvent(ev) {
        if (ev.target.innerText == 'Do it')
            this.log()
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = '<button>Do it</button>'
        this.addEventListener('click', this)
    }
})
```

```html
<first-component></first-component>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what the security reasons are?

Comment: @user2939415 search for "javascript injection" or read for example https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/disable-inline-javascript-for-security/

Comment: Is there an approach similar to getRootNode() for web components that don't use Shadow DOM?

Comment: @user2939415 yes: `"this.closest('first-component').log()"` should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't be `log()`, but `this.log()`, because that `log` function scope is only that element, not in `window` scope, so your code should be

```
customElements.define('first-component', class FirstComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
     }

     log() {
        console.log('Well Done!')
     }

     connectedCallback()
        this.innerHTML = '<button onclick="this.parentElement.log()">Do it</button>'
     }
});
```

-- EDIT --
Sorry, my mistake, I just saw that you added button inside custom element, well... It should be `this.parentElement.log()` if you still want to prefer inline

Comment: Also tried that before. The Problem is that this will bind to the button and also fail.

Comment: Did you even try this? This does not work, `this` is still the window scope here

Comment: oops, sorry, well you can try `this.parentElement.log()`

Answer (score 0):

Since the DOM and its elements does not have any knowledge of the scope it lives in, just setting the value of the innerHTML won't work since `log` does not exist on `window` which is the DOM scope. Hence this, it's best practice to create the element and append it to the Shadow Dom of the custom element and at the same time add the eventListener to the button.

```js
customElements.define('first-component', class FirstComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
     }

     log() {
        console.log('Well Done!')
     }

     connectedCallback() { // This parentheses was also missing
         var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
         const button = document.createElement("button");
         button.textContent = 'Do it!';
         button.addEventListener('click', () => this.log());
         shadow.appendChild(button);
     }
});
```

```html
<first-component id="component"></first-component>
```

Comment: It works but I dislike this solution, haha ! Thank you

Comment: Not sure if there is any other solutions tbh @Fabian . I guess you can have a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866237/click-event-not-firing-when-react-component-in-a-shadow-dom to see if that helps, I know it's pointing to react but it more or less native

Answer (score 0):

You should - for many reasons - **stop using inline event listeners**. Instead, use `addEventListener` - in this case in the `connectedCallback`.

```js
customElements.define('first-element', class FirstElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
     }

     log() {
        console.log('Well Done!')
     }

     connectedCallback() {
        const btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.textContent = 'Do it!';
        btn.type = 'button'; // otherwise it's type=submit
        btn.addEventListener('click', this.log);
        this.appendChild(btn);
     }
});
```

```html
<first-element></first-element>
```

Comment: Why is using inline event listeners bad? I think its more readable and many Frameworks follow this pattern

Comment: Those frameworks parse the HTML and replace the inline event listeners with `addEventListener` internally. With native web components, you're in a different context. Inline event listeners - aside from being bad for the same reasons inline styles are bad - also do not comply with content security policy which cannot be applied on code using inline event listeners.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach using template literals and window properties.

By using template literals you get the scope you want, but the `onclick` event still needs access to your method. I guess using `window` is the only way to share something from outer scope for the event in this case. Since the event takes in string type, I can just make it call `window` and some unique property name where the shared method lives in.

```js
customElements.define('first-component', class FirstComponent extends HTMLElement {
   log() {
      console.log('Well Done!')
   }

   bind(callback) {
     if (!callback) return '';
     const name = 'generate_random_name';
     window[name] = callback;
     return `window.${name}();`;
   }

   connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<button onclick=${this.bind(() => this.log())}>Do it</button>`
   }
});
```

```html
<first-component></first-component>
```

To go a little bit further, we can also get rid of the `bind` method by using a tagged template literal. This allows us to manipulate the template string and it's dynamic values before they get rendered. Naming the tag to "html" is useful because it enables html's syntax highlighting.

```js
function html(strings, ...values) {
  let str = '';
  strings.forEach((string, index) => {
    const value = values[index];
    if (typeof value === 'function') {
      const callback = value;
      const name = 'generate_random_name';
      window[name] = callback;
      str += string + `window.${name}();`;
    } else {
      str += string
    }
  });
  return str;
}

customElements.define('first-component', class FirstComponent extends HTMLElement {
  log() {
    console.log('Well Done!')
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = html`<button onclick=${() => this.log()}>Do it</button>`
  }
});
```

```html
<first-component></first-component>
```