# How to get custom element member variable from inline event handler?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, native-web-component

Because I would like to keep the custom element self-contained, I want to avoid putting a reference to the member variable on the `window` object.

```
customElements.define( 'component-one', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.memberVariable="This is a member variable";
        this.innerHTML = "<button onclick='//How do I reference the above this.memberVariable here?'>This is a button</button>";
    }
}):
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access class function in Web Component from inline Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53963583/access-class-function-in-web-component-from-inline-element)

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this will help -:

```
customElements.define( 'component-one', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        var self = this;
        this.memberVariable="This is a member variable";
        this.innerHTML = "<button onclick='self.memberVariable // use this variable as required'>This is a button</button>";
    }
}):
```

Comment: I tested this code, and it appears that `self` refers to `window` inside the event handler.  Were you able to get this code to work?